# Can I use Eucalyptus with two clusters in different places?

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus

I'm learning about Eucalyptus to my master degree and I want know if I can use Eucalyptus in the following situation.

City A: All infrasctruct configured with cluster, nodes, CLC...
and City B with another cluster. 
In the city B can I just install CC and configure him to be part of the infrastructure of city A?

Can two infrastructure of different places became a logical one?

sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All components should be in a similar location, as is the case for a [region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-regions-availability-zones) in AWS. There would be a CC ([cluster controller](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#install-guide/euca_components.html)) and SC (storage controller) for each cluster within the cloud (so for each availability zone) and also some NCs (node controllers)

It may be possible to run with a CC/SC/NC (node controller) in a different location, but the cloud will perform poorly if there is high latency or low bandwidth between locations, and you'd have to meet the [network requirements](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#install-guide/system_requirements.html), such as multicast.

Comment: Another network requirement that is difficult to meet over WAN is to enable a pool of cloud-wide public IP addresses to be routable to either of the CCs. It is doable with tunnels, but would be fragile and wouldn't perform well.